# Is it possible to manually mark/unmark an object for garbage collection?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, weak-references

Most resources state that the garbage collector figures that out on its own based on references and that I shouldn't mess with it.

I am wondering if I can explicitly  tell the garbage collector that it *may* dispose an object while still keeping a reference.

What I would like to do is to tell the garbage collector that I currently don't need an object anymore (but might again) and then at a later point when (if) I need the object again I would like to check if it has been disposed already. If it has I simply recreate it, if it hasn't I'd like to "unmark" it from garbage collection until I am done with it again.

Is this possible?

I plan to implement something similar to the `Lazy<T>` class. Pseudocode:

```
obj = new DisposeIfNecessary<LargeObject>(() => InitLargeObject());
obj.DoSomething(); // Initializes obj using InitLargeObject()
obj.DisposeIfNecessary(); // This is where the magic happens

... // obj might get disposed at some point

obj.DoAnotherThing(); // Might or might not call InitLargeObject() again
obj.Dispose(); // I will not need it again
```

Comment: Not "most resources", all of them.  Dispose() has nothing to do with garbage collection.  If you disposed an object and you want to use it afterwards anyway then you're doing it wrong.  Just don't dispose it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`WeakReference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class does exactly what you want, using the `IsAlive` property to check for state before using it.

You can get a "strong" reference to it again via the `Target` property, which will affect the reference count and stop it from being eligible for collection.

Also note that `Dispose` doesn't directly relate to garbage collection, so disposing an item (depending on the `Dispose` implementation) might make it unusable anyway - but again, that is nothing to do with GC. On a general practice note, as mentioned by @HansPassant, calling `Dispose` on an item (or generally anything claiming to dispose) and then attempting to use it again afterwards is a code smell (or just plain wrong as other developers will expect `Dispose` to be a last-call method marking the object as unusable from then on).

The `WeakReference` class will not be responsible for re-creating collected objects, but in conjunction with `IsAlive` you can handle that logic yourself.

Also, to the point in the comments, the GC doesn't do anything clever with `WeakReference` in terms of deciding when to collect it in terms of trying to leave `WeakReference` items until last; it will collect the underlying object as it would others during a run if it is eligible - no special handling and definitely no "cache" behaviour.

Comment: Note that WeakReference is not a cache, it's not a "throw it out if you absolutely need to", but a "you can check if it has been thrown out".

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Ah, I'll amend my answer to cover your point.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for!
I'd accept the answer but while this does solve my problem it doesn't really answer the original question...

@Lasse: I'm indeed looking for a cache that only removes objects if it really becomes necessary. Do you have a better idea on how I would achieve that or would you go with `WeakReference` too?

Comment: @RomanReiner So far as I can read from your original question, it addresses both points: checking for the object, creating it if you need to, or stopping it from being GC'd if it hasn't yet. You don't actually mention any cache semantics in your question at all...

Comment: WeakReference does in no way prevent collection of a "referenced" object. It only allows you to retrieve a reference to the object *if it hasn't been collected*. Let me rephrase. Having only a WeakReference to an object will not affect the garbage collector in any way. If the object would be collected if you had no WeakReference to it, it will be collected even if you have one. So basically, it is not a "cache until absolutely necessary to collect". I don't know of any such class or construct however, though that's definitely not saying that there isn't one. I just don't know of it.

Comment: There is a [Cache Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache(v=vs.110).aspx) though, however it is "cache for a web application". Unsure if you can use it outside of one.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Not sure if that was to me or Roman. @Roman, the "caching" solution you want will need to use something like `WeakReference` in order to get the necessary hooks into the GC if you want to utilise the GC as a stale object collector. Of course, caches do not make use of the GC to keep the cache memory in check, most caches implement their own LRU LFU style logic to empty items from the cache and don't care what the GC does or doesn't do.

Comment: I wouldn't use GC as a stale object collector. I *might* want to use it as a "trigger when GC is running" type of thing, but I would probably want to add some other checks, such as how much memory is consumed/free. Then of course you need to know something about the objects being cached, ie. how much would it help to release 1, 10, 100, etc.